# taking data from .xls file to python list

Tags: python

Open the workbook

```
import xlrd
wb = xlrd.open_workbook('/home/AlAhAb65/Desktop/Parameter.xls')
```

Check the sheet names

```
wb.sheet_names()
```

Get the first sheet either by name

```
sh = wb.sheet_by_name('QA_TEST')
l = []
```

Iterate through rows, returning each as a list that you can index:

```
for rownum in range(sh.nrows):
    l.append(sh.row_values(rownum))
print l
```

When I am reading from excel to python list there always come ‘u’ before every data. How can I get rid of this? Is everything read as string? Do I have to convert every time?

Comment: It means they're unicode (as they should be stored in excel) - why does this bother you? (eg: does it cause encoding issues later/etc...)

Comment: And just an aside, instead of your loop, in Python 2.x you can use - `map(ws.row_values, xrange(sh.nrows))` instead

Comment: Yes, Encoding issue occurs. I need to get rid of this because I need to send this value (as float or integer) to another program. That 'u' makes problem for this

Comment: You'll get unicode when the entries are strings in the sheet, if they're numeric, you'll get them as floats... so could you elaborate on the exact problem you're having?

Answer (score 1):

The 'u' is not part of the string, it comes before the quotes and indicates a unicode string, which should be fine.

Also, you may want to have a look at the more recent [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).